# The variable return zero

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to dig a row and update it in a database but the variable keeps returning 0.

```
        int uamId = Convert.ToInt32(lblId.Text);
        tbl_UAM uam = new tbl_UAM();
        using (var context = new DemoDbEntities())
        {
            var uamToUpdate = context.tbl_UAM.SingleOrDefault(UpDateuam => uamId == uam.Id);
            if(uamToUpdate!=null)
            {
                uamToUpdate.MDMRefNumber = tbxMDMRefNum.Text;
                uamToUpdate.SARId = tbxSARId.Text;
                uamToUpdate.DateOfBirthInGreenCard = tbxDoBGreenCard.Text;
                uamToUpdate.DateOfBirthUAM = tbxDoBUAM.Text;
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

The `uam.Id` at `var uamToUpdate = context.tbl_UAM.SingleOrDefault(UpDateuam => uamId == uam.Id);` is always 0. so in my `if` statement, the answer is always false and I can't update it. what am I doing wrong that the `uam.Id` always returns 0 ?

Comment: In the second line you have tbl_UAM uam = new tbl_UAM();
Does it instantiate a new id for uam object? If not, then you won't have a matching id and hence the result will always be 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant this (Look at the predicate in `SingleOrDefault`)

```
int uamId = Convert.ToInt32(lblId.Text);
        tbl_UAM uam = new tbl_UAM();
        using (var context = new DemoDbEntities())
        {
            var uamToUpdate = context.tbl_UAM.SingleOrDefault(upDateuam => upDateuam.Id == uamId);
            if(uamToUpdate!=null)
            {
                uamToUpdate.MDMRefNumber = tbxMDMRefNum.Text;
                uamToUpdate.SARId = tbxSARId.Text;
                uamToUpdate.DateOfBirthInGreenCard = tbxDoBGreenCard.Text;
                uamToUpdate.DateOfBirthUAM = tbxDoBUAM.Text;
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: How can i not see that!!!!!!!!!!!!! I've been on this since morning! thanks a lot mate

Answer (score 2):

You are intializing uam at second line

i think you meant this:

```
 int uamId = Convert.ToInt32(lblId.Text);
 using (var context = new DemoDbEntities())
    {
        var uamToUpdate = context.tbl_UAM.SingleOrDefault(UpDateuam => UpDateuam.Id == uamId);
        if(uamToUpdate!=null)
        {
            uamToUpdate.MDMRefNumber = tbxMDMRefNum.Text;
            uamToUpdate.SARId = tbxSARId.Text;
            uamToUpdate.DateOfBirthInGreenCard = tbxDoBGreenCard.Text;
            uamToUpdate.DateOfBirthUAM = tbxDoBUAM.Text;
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you meant to do this:

```
var uamToUpdate = context.tbl_UAM.SingleOrDefault(UpDateuam => UpDateuam.Id == uamId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are comparing the uam.Id in your predicate which is newly created instance? So it will always be zero and it will not find any records in the database. So your condition is failing.